# Cocoa pods migration issue to Swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift2, swift3, xcode8

Is there are any convenient way to migrate to Swift 3 from 2.3 version?

I opened Xcode 8 and pressed later button when it asked me to migrate.

Now I have this issue:

```
“Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.
```

So what are my next step, should I keep it legacy or should I select Xcode menu Edit > Convert to Swift 3.

I have some pods libraries which is looks like updated to Swift 3, but maybe some of them it's still under 2.3

What is the better way to migrate.

1. How to avoid pods library issue?
2. What is the Use Legacy Swift Language Version, will it works with two different Swift versions?

Answer (score 0):

Hover over edit at the top of Xcode 
click convert
click "to current swift syntax"
click next 2x
let it work click save
now hit command B it will build and all those errors will go away.
It might still have some but must probably will tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to convert syntax to 2.3(same) when prompted instead of selecting swift 3, unless you're required nor want to do so.

How to avoid pods library issue?
If you choose swift 3, after you click next you will have an option as to which framewrok/pod/project you wish to be converted, just unselect the framework/pod and let alone the project be converted.

What is the Use Legacy Swift Language Version, will it works with two different Swift versions?
with pod as 2.3 and main project as 3 it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress this warning by adding the following to your `Podfile`:

```
  post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
          end
      end
  end
```